# Should a question be corrected if OP misremembered something then found it out from the answer, or should it be left as it is?

Tags: discussion

I was reading [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72045/identify-a-movie-about-boys-imprisoned-after-injured-killed-a-men-with-an-hot-do) question and its answer, where OP misremembered something and when he found out the correct "thing" from the answer, corrected it. So I'm wondering, is it better to correct it or leave it as it is?

For me, I think the question shouldn't be changed to match the answer, but is there's anything in the rules/guidelines suggest one way or the other?

Answer (score 3):

Questions **should not** be edited to correct misremembered information based on Answers received even by the OP.

Although the OP is permitted to edit the question to ADD information, and should be encouraged to do so, **changing** the question is not recommended and the **edit rolled back**.

---

In this case, the change is a minor one and the Answer has already been accepted.

A Rollback is a possibility but, *in this case*, I would argue it's not worth the potential hassle.

Comment: I disagree.  While in this particular case the misremembered detail wasn't THAT important, in other cases it could mean the difference between light and day if the asker realizes a detail is wrong in their question and corrects it, whether it was prompted by a correct answer or not.

Comment: Which is my point.... **in this case** it's not worth the hassle but in general these should be rolled back. Added note to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The point of being able to edit a question is to allow the refinement of said question in order to get the answer the asker is looking for.  Sometimes, askers start off with incomplete information, whether they know it or not.

For ID questions, sometimes the asker misremembers a plot detail.  Later on they might realize that a detail, or even a whole scene, is wrong (ie, they mixed two movies).  The correct action here, imho, is for **the asker** to edit the question to make it clear which movie they are wanting to identify by removing the extraneous details.

Comment: But once a question (ID question) been answered, we can add all the details we want and make it a perfect question, I don't think we or the OP should though.

Comment: @madmada this is for the rare case that a detail was wrong and the op decided to fix it in their question.  it's not common to go back to a question once a correct answer has been found and then ADD details from the correct answer (that's not how SE works).  those sorts of edits SHOULD be rolled back.

Comment: I know, but I'm saying that both things are very similar.